# How to debug contracts?

Tags: smartcontracts

When writing a contract, the output of `aeproject compile` is completely unhelpful:

```
===== Compiling contracts =====

Contract 'foo.aes has not been compiled'
reason:
undefined
```

Is there a way to get a more specific reason than `undefined`?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler should have a response with a comprehensive message of what went wrong already.
Please update your version of `aeproject` to `@2.1.0` and come back to us with feedback if this works for you.

Best regards